# Highcharts randomises colors instead of starting from left to right each time

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts to display some graphs in a project and I've set some custom colors using this:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors: ['#404040', '#87d5e4', '#4999d4', '#ffce92', '#f39180', '#eb7a9b', '#8a84e2', '#07c1db',
             '#26b8bd', '#2380be', '#ffaa34', '#fd6d51', '#de3a6a', '#5f59b8', '#009ebe', '#009297', '#f2f2f2',
             '#fcecda', '#ffd2ca', '#febfc5']
});
```

The problem with this is that it just randomises colors from this array rather than starting from left to right. So on each page refresh it's a different color, I want this behavior to stop.

How can I do this? I can't find any setting for this in [the docs](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/colors).

Comment: just set one color on each page refresh and mark those which were set previously

Comment: Could you give more specific information about your problem? I have made an example with your code and it looks the same every time I am refreshing my site: https://jsfiddle.net/paLoxcy3/5/

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I need to set all colors at once so that it can use all.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński I'm investigating using your example, seems weird that they don't behave the same.

Comment: It may be connected with the code how you are loading your data to your chart. Maybe they are not always rendered in the same order?

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński Could be, there's a lot of things happening before the data even reaches the config object of the chart. I make an api call, format the data, creates categories and then forwards it to the config object where I set the data property amongst other properties.

Comment: We need a specific example. It feels like you're not generating the chart series in the same order on each refresh but can't know that for sure until we get some more code.

Comment: So if you want to have the same color of your series, you can always add it manually to every series using series.color parameter. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<area>.color

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński But that would leave all series looking the same, would it not?

Comment: Not really, every series may have different color, for example http://jsfiddle.net/rrLckLs0/

Comment: What you want is the default behavior. Highcharts pulls from the color array in order. If your colors are loading differently, it usually means that you're removing and adding series, which will then cycle through the array rather than starting at the beginning. If that's not the case, set up a fiddle to recreate the problem.

Answer (score -1):

highcharts always take colors form left to right

See Example

```js
Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors: ['#058DC7', '#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4']
});



var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        defaultSeriesType: 'pie'
    },
    
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```